# LINQ doesn't end with certain characters

Tags: c#, linq

The Linq I have below is note complete but you get the idea:
I need to check that TruckNbr does not end in "100" or "1000".
How do I do this in the query below

```
    var truck = (from tr in DataContext.Trucks
                 where tr.TruckNbr != ... 
                 select tr).ToList()
```

Comment: Is `TruckNbr` really a number or is it a `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming TruckNbr is a string.

```
var truck = (from tr in DataContext.Trucks
             where !(tr.TruckNbr.EndsWith("100") || tr.TruckNbr.EndsWith("1000"))
             select tr).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

If `TruckNbr` is a `varchar` in the database you can do this:

```
var truck = (from tr in DataContext.Trucks
             where tr.TruckNbr.EndsWith("100") == false
                && tr.TruckNbr.EndsWith("1000") == false
             select tr).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers assumed `TruckNbr` is a string; here's how you would do it assuming `TruckNbr` is a number:

```
var truck = (from tr in DataContext.Trucks
             where tr.TruckNbr%1000 != 100 && tr.TruckNbr%10000 != 1000
             select tr).ToList()
```